# TypeError at /main 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Столкнулся с проблемой, я запарсил данные во views.py и добавил запрос на добавление данных в бд, но почему выскакивает ошибка

```
TypeError at /main
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Это весь трейсбек

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from list_item.models import item
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req


def main(request):
    link = 'https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/uk/shop/mobilnye_telefony_smartfon.html'
    res = req.get(link)
    html = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    for name in html.find_all("a", class_="card__title"):
    
        name = item.objects.create(name=name, price=1000, reviews=6, category='mobile', ful_url='none' )
        name.save()
    return render(request, 'main/main.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE



class item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    reviews = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ful_url = models.CharField(max_length=1500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: «Это весь трейсбек» — не, он не может быть такой весь. Поищите весь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это была довольно глупая ошибка, в строке, а точнее в цикле

```
for name in html.find_all("a", class_="card__title"):
    
        name = item.objects.create(name=name, price=1000, reviews=6, category='mobile', ful_url='none' )
        name.save()
```

Я должен был использовать экземпляр класса `name1`,а не `name`, чтобы получить

```
for name in html.find_all("a", class_="card__title"):
    
        name1 = item.objects.create(name=name.text, price=1000, reviews=6, category='mobile', ful_url='none' )
        name1.save()
```